# How can externalResource communicate with mainWindow in Vaadin

Tags: oauth, window, vaadin

I have a vaadin application running, and now, I have a button, by clicking that, it will open a externalResource (e.g  `getMainWindow().open(new ExternalResource("http://google.com"), "Google", 800, 600, Window.BORDER_NONE);)`. This works fine. but how can the main app knows when I close that externalResource window? The thing is I wanna add Oauth to app, and when it's done, user close the window, the app page should be refreshed automatically? If this way doesn't work, is there any other ways solve it? Thanks

Comment: you want it only by using popup window??

Comment: @umeshawasthi  yes, the original page cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab that is opened with getMainWindow().open(new ExternalResource(...)) is not managed by Vaadin, so you cannot be notified when it is closed.

You can embed a browser frame in your application:

```
Embedded browser = new Embedded("", new ExternalResource("http://google.com"));
browser.setType(Embedded.TYPE_BROWSER);
main.addComponent(browser);
```

If you need this in a separate window, add that window to the application (not to the main window) and open it:

```
addWindow(secondWindow);
main.open(new ExternalResource(secondWindow.getURL()), "_new");
```

Comment: I tried using Embedded one, it works for opening the window, but the concept there is put the content in a frame, but some Oauth doesn't allow it in frames. so that way cannot work in this scenario. About the separate window, the secondWindow.getURL() is the combination of app's url and window name. but in this case. if set window name with "http://www.google.com" the url will be "http://hostname:portnumber/app/http://www.google.com". or did I miss anything?

Comment: The window name cannot be "http://www,google.com", it will be part of your own URL. If you cannot use frames, you're out of luck. How do you think you will get Javascript into the external site that will notify your server when the page is closed? That would constitute an XSS attack.

Comment: alright, seems I have to find another way. anyway, thank you for you kind help.